# How to open pgsql file on Windows?

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

I downloaded a 7 Gigabyte .pgsql file.

What do I need to download in order to open this file on my Windows 7 machine?

I tried installing PostgreSQL 9.1 for Windows, but when I open the pgAdmin it keeps asking me for a server, and I don't have any. All I want is to open an existing file, how can I configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7 GB - this is probably a backup file either of a (big) database or a whole db cluster.
To restore it, you need a working Postgres server installation (and possibly a database to restore to). You would have to tell us more about the file.

Be aware that a 7 GB backup in uncompressed text format typically results in a database with somewhere around 20 GB disk space. But that can vary wildly.

If it is plain SQL (indicated by the file extension `.pgsql`) you can restore it by feeding it to the standard command line client [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

```sh
psql -p $PORT $db -U $username -f /path/to/file.pgsql
```

[pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) is a graphical administration tool (you seem to confuse it with the RDBMS itself). It offers restore capabilities, too.

If it is an archive file created with [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), you need to use [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

For a file that big it might pay to optimize restore performance. Here is a [Postgres Wiki entry](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bulk_Loading_and_Restores) on that.

Postgres version, encoding and locale of the dump and the database (cluster) have to be compatible. If you don't know any of that, I recommend you start by reading about [backup and restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html). Or more generally, about [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html).

Comment: Thank you Erwin. The file has the pgsql extension and I believe it's a plain SQL. I don't understand how to restore it via command line - I tried the Postgre9.1 command line option from the start menu but it asks me for a server to connect to. I'm afraid I'm missing the point here, must I have a server in order to view some pgsql file? Thanks again :) Nili

Comment: @Nili: PostgreSQL initializes a db cluster at installation (out of the box) which should be available at the standard port 5432. You need a running server process and a database cluster to restore to. Depending on the nature of the file you may also need a database to restore to. *Or*, if you have the DDL commands to create the database at the start of your file (CREATE DATABASE ...), you can connect to the maintainance db "postgres". You will have to familiarize yourself with the concept of the RDBMS in order to handle this.